# How to represent an AR(2) process in the MA($\infty$) form?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autoregressive, moving-average

I am new in statistics and I really would like to learn about it. I am studying the ARMA processes and I have some doubts.

Suppose I have an AR(2) process like the following one:
$$X_t=\phi_1X_{t-1}+\phi_2X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t,$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is a  white noise.

I would like to write this process in the MA($\infty$) form and I found in this website a similar exercise in which they do the following.
The polynomial associated to my process is this: $p(x)=1-\phi_1x-\phi_2x^2$. This means that
$$ p(L)X_t=\epsilon_t.$$

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the two roots of the polynomial $p(x)$ and let $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{z_1}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{z_2}$.

I can rewrite $p(x)=(1-\lambda_1 x)(1-\lambda_2 x)$. My first question is related to this step. I know that
$$p(x)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)=z_1z_2(1-\lambda_1x)(1-\lambda_2x).$$
Am I wrong? Why the constants $z_1$ and $z_2$ don't appear?

And after they do the following
$$X_t=\frac{1}{(1-\lambda_1L)(1-\lambda_2L)}\epsilon_t$$
and they say to expand the functions $\frac{1}{1-\lambda_iL$.
If I do this I should obtain the following:

$$X_t=\Bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\phi_1^iL^i\Bigg)\Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi_2^jL^j\Bigg)\epsilon_t.$$
If the expation that I wrote is correct how can I conclude the MA($\infty$) expression for the process?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Taylor_series

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. The expansion that is suggested in wikipedia gives a MA(q) process with q finite. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it gives you the Taylor expansion of $1/p(L)$, i.e., the polynomial of the MA$(\infty)$ representation of the process.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just realized my error! I have another question about that. The Taylor expansion gives a different representation respect to the one given by the Wold theorem?